# has errors in the manager reporting structure

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

**> People search relevance is not optimized when the Active Directory has

> errors in the manager reporting structure.**

In Active Directory, only company leaders should have the 'manager' property set to NULL. As a result of errors, the Active Directory can incorrectly have the 'manager' property set to NULL for other users that can cause a decrease in people search relevance. By specifying the actual leaders of the company, these inconsistencies are not taken into account and the relevance problem is corrected.

Why am I getting this message, and how do I resolve the problem?

Comment: What are you asking? You are only quoting a message in CA

Comment: How to resolve and why this ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all. The source where you import user profiles from (AD probably) seems to have incomplete information regarding managerial structure.

You get this message if not the very most of your users have the Manager filled in in AD. To make it go away, make sure this field it filled in on all employees except the top manager (CIO etc)